# Find a value by key from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an huge array of object and need to find the name of object by key, how can I do that with the optimized way.

```
const key = 2;
const arr = [ {id: 1, text: '1111'},  {id: 2, text: '2222'}, {id: 3, text: '333'},]
```

I need to return only the text '2222'
The original array have an 154 object thats why I need the most optimized way.

```
arr.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        console.log("key : " + key + " - value : " + obj[key]);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you try [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: Is it possible for you to store the data in an object instead? eg `{ 1: { text: '1111' }, 2: { text: '2222' }, ... }`. Then you could access it with `yourObject[key]`. That's the only way to make it efficient afaik

Comment: There is a search feature at the top of the page which can be used to find answers to common questions like this one.   [Example Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+find+object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has great array methods to do these kind of things. In your case I would use `array.find` to achieve what you're after. You can read more about it **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

```
const key = 2;
const arr = [ {id: 1, text: '1111'},  {id: 2, text: '2222'}...]

const result = arr.find((item) => item.id === key).text;
console.log(result) // will print '2222'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `forEach` or `for` loop

In term of optimisation `for loop` is the fastest one

```js
var key = 2;
const arr = [ {id: 1, text: '1111'},  {id: 2, text: '2222'}, {id: 3, text: '333'},]

arr.forEach((obj) => {
      if (obj.id == key) {
        console.log(obj.text);
      }
});


for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i].id == key) {
        console.log(arr[i].text)  
     }        
}
```